# Use of C# method/property in a MATLAB try/catch operator

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have developed a driver for an automated microscopy system, written in C# and compiled using Visual Studio 2013. I have a peculiar issue when assigning some of the properties in a `try`/`catch` loop.

Below is a sample of MATLAB code (simplified for display).

```
pwsAssembly = NET.addAssembly ( 'file location' );
scope = Pws . Scope ( );
scope . Connect();

% This command performs the movement.
scope . Objective = 1;

% This command DOES NOT perform the movement, but DOES NOT enter the catch statement.
try
  scope . Objective = 4;
catch
  error ( 'Unable to adjust objective' );
end

% Again, this command performs the movement:
scope . Objective = 4;
```

The `Objective` is a `Get`/`Set` property within the `Scope` class.

Any ideas on why the `Set` of the C# property would not perform properly within a MATLAB `try`/`catch` statement?

**MORE DETAILS**

I have further characterized the behavior in MATLAB.

1. If I execute the code as a script, without breaks or pauses, some operations are skipped over.
2. If I "step" through the script, each line is executed as intended, even in a `try`/`catch` operator.
3. If the property assignment is inside an `if` statement, it is always successful.

Below is modified MATLAB code to reflect this observation.

```
pwsAssembly = NET . addAssembly ( 'fileLocation' );
scope = Pws . Scope ( );
scope . Connect ( );

scope . Objective = 1; % Unsuccessful. Successful if I "step" through.

try
  scope . Objective = 4; % Unsuccessful . Successful if I "step" through.
catch
  error ( 'Headaches' );
end

if ( scope . Objective  ~= 6 )
  scope . Objective = 6; % Successful, always.
end
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with a small made-up assembly, but I cannot reproduce the problem:

#### Scope.cs

```cs
using System;
namespace PWS
{
    public class Scope
    {
        public int Objective { get; set; }

        public Scope()
        {
            Objective = 0;
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("connected");
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled it into an assembly using:

```
C:\> csc.exe /target:library Scope.cs
```

#### MATLAB

Here is the code to use it in MATLAB:

```matlab
>> NET.addAssembly(fullfile(pwd,'Scope.dll'));

>> scope = PWS.Scope();
>> scope.Connect();

>> scope.Objective = 1;
>> try, scope.Objective = 4, catch ME, error('failed'); end
>> if (scope.Objective ~= 6), scope.Objective = 6; end
```

All lines ran fine no matter how I run the code: executed interactively in the command window, run as either a script or function, either normally or while stepping through the code in the debugger.

*(Note: any calls to `Console.WriteLine` wont normally show up in MATLAB, although there are ways to [capture the output from .NET](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97098-how-can-i-have-system-console-writeline-write-to-the-matlab-command-window-while-using-the-net-api))*

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Amro. I am able to reproduce your response above. There is a considerable amount of logic behind the property set within my assembly, not just a simple assignment.  The set operation is fully blocking though,  so I really am at a loss.

Comment: @Juderb: I figured as much, the devil is always in the detail.. Can you show the kind of code you have in the `set` method? Also can you review the list of [known limitations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-net-from-matlab-an-overview.html#brpb58f-1), maybe there is something in there that is affecting you..

Comment: I will upload some details. It will happen later today, as I have work to complete before I get the time.